# How to filter a csv separated by tabs?

Tags: bash, awk

I have the following problem, I need to extract some lines of a large csv separated by tabs that looks as follows:

```
organe organ     hkl0094508      g67      1       LBNhkl23        AcorFive  sentiment        PENDLEorFON WOOLEN MIL    REWS Managed Services                            LBEAN   1-800-SFFA-CALL                                                                                                   N
organe organ     hkl0968175377   g67      1       GNSFORJL        AcorFive  sentiment        NesorF Labs for JL        .                               .       .                       N
organe organ     hkl099999       g67      1       INorFEL385        AcorFive  sentiment        FRYS    REWS Managed Services                            B2B orFech SuppororF        916-356-1234                                                                                                     N
organe organ     hkl108860       g67      1       INorFEL976        ACorFIVE  sentiment        RYOYO   .       .       .       .       .       .                                       N
```

The idea is to extract only the lines that match in the second column with a specific list:

```
hkl0968175377
hkl0094508
```

The fist approach that I tried was to use awk, as follows:
I am typing the tab with the verbatin mode, pressing ctrl v,

```
awk -F "      " 'FNR==NR{seen[$1]; next} $2 in seen' patterns original_list > new_list
```

but when I make:

```
$ wc -l new_list
0 new_list
```

I got 0 lines, my desired output would be an archive called new_list with the following two lines:

```
organe organ     hkl0968175377   g67      1       GNSFORJL        AcorFive  sentiment        NesorF Labs for JL        .                               .       .                       N
organe organ     hkl0094508      g67      1       LBNhkl23        AcorFive  sentiment        PENDLEorFON WOOLEN MIL    REWS Managed Services                            LBEAN   1-800-SFFA-CALL                                                                                                   N
```

I would like to appreciate any suggestion to overcome this situation.

Comment: If your input files and code were as you've stated then you'd get the output you expect. So, to debug your files add print statements in your script to print FS, $1 from the first file, and $2 from the 2nd file with delimiters in a way you can see exactly what they are, e.g. `printf "<%s>\n",$1`.

Comment: I don't think your field separator is correct.  Try with `-F'  +'` (two or more spaces)

Comment: Or if your data (or script) has passed thru a Windows OS system, it likely has `\r\n` line-endings. Clean them up by running `dos2unix data1.txt data2.txt .... myScript.sh ....` Each file will be replaced with a `\n` only version. Good luck.

Comment: I understand, in fact, my data passed thru a Windows system maybe I need to clean it, thanks for the timely observation, I appreciate the support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm reading your question correctly, you actually want `grep`, specifically `grep -f`, e.g.

```
grep -f list full_file
```

Where `list` contains

```
hkl0968175377
hkl0094508
```

and `full_file` is you full tab-delimited file. `grep` will search for occurrences in `list` in `full_file`.

**Output**

```
$ grep -f list full_file
organe organ     hkl0094508      g67      1       LBNhkl23        AcorFive  sentiment        PENDLEorFON WOOLEN MIL    REWS Managed Services                            LBEAN   1-800-SFFA-CALL                                                                                                   N
organe organ     hkl0968175377   g67      1       GNSFORJL        AcorFive  sentiment        NesorF Labs for JL        .                               .       .                       N
```

(you can `sort` the results order if that is important, and *note:*, this simple method presume the keys in list only appear in one column of your output and are not repeated in various columns throughout)

Comment: Works for the data provided, but can get tripped  up if the "keys" appear in other columns of data (We never know what the O.P really has ;-/ ) . Good luck to all.

Comment: Thanks this was the best approach since I don't need to take care about the position of the columns, I believe that for this specific task grep is best than awk, thanks for the support.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

`awk -F '\t' 'FNR==NR{seen[$1]=1; next} seen[$2]' patterns original_list > new_list`

That's the shorter way. Or, for a little easier readability (changing `seen` to `keys`):

`awk -F '\t' 'FNR==NR{keys[$1]=1; next} ($2 in keys) { print $0 }' patterns original_list > new_list`

In English:

*If processing file 1, load the first field of each line into the array `keys`. Otherwise, we are processing file 2, so if the value of field 2 is contained in `keys`, then print the line*